# JAVA: ImmutableSet as List

Tags: java, list, immutable-collections

I currently get returned an ImmutableSet from a function call (getFeatures()) and due to the structure of the rest of my code to be executed later on- it would be much easier to change this to a List. I have tried to cast it which produces a runtime exception. I have also looked around for a function call to convert it to a list to no avail. Is there a way to do this? My most recent [failed] attempt is shown below:

```
ImmutableSet<FeatureWrapper> wrappersSet =  getFeatures();
List<FeatureWrapper> wrappers = (List<FeatureWrapper>) wrappersSet;
```

I have found wrapperSet.asList() which will give me an ImmutableList however i would much rather prefer a mutable list

Comment: make a new List of it: List<FeatureWrapper> wrappers = ImmutableList.builder().addAll( wrappersSet ).build();

Comment: Why do you want a mutable list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't cast a `Set<T>` into a `List<T>`. They are entirely-different objects. Just use this [<s>copy</s> constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) which creates a new list out of a collection:

```
List<FeatureWrapper> wrappers = new ArrayList<>(wrappersSet);
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. I knew there was a simple way to do this that I was missing! Thank you will accept shortly

Answer (score 6):

`ImmutableCollection` has the "[asList](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html#asList())" function...

```
ImmutableList<FeatureWrapper> wrappersSet = getFeatures().asList();
```

Bonus points that the returned type an `ImmutableList`.

If you really wanted a mutable `List` though, then [Vivin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761427/java-immutableset-as-list#answer-30761462) answer is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Guava-21` supports `java-8` you can use `stream` and `collector` to convert an `ImmutableSet` to a `List`:

```
ImmutableSet<Integer> intSet = ImmutableSet.of(1,2,3,4,5);
// using java-8 Collectors.toList()
List<Integer> integerList = intSet.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(integerList); // [1,2,3,4,5]
integerList.removeIf(x -> x % 2 == 0); 
System.out.println(integerList); // [1,3,5] It is a list, we can add 
// and remove elements
```

We can use `ImmutableList#toImmutableList` with collectors to convert an `ImmutableList` to a `ImmutableList` :
// using ImmutableList#toImmutableList()

```
ImmutableList<Integer> ints = intSet.stream().collect(
                                     ImmutableList.toImmutableList()
                              );
System.out.println(ints); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And the easiest way is to call `ImmutableSet#asList`

```
// using ImmutableSet#asList
ImmutableList<Integer> ints = intSet.asList();
```